# laravel how to get image information from relationship and optimize it

Tags: laravel, optimization, relationship

**Product model**
id  (column)
productname  (column)

**ProductGallery model**
galleryid (column)
productid (column)

**Galleries model**
id (column)
imagename (column)

hello i want retrive data like this, my model is in the top

```
"id" => 1
productname => "product 1"
galleries => {
   0 => {
         id => 1,
         imagename => 'image 1'
        }
   1 => {
         id => 2,
         imagename => 'image 2'
        }
}
```

how can i achive this using relationship and optimize?

Comment: so it's a N to N relationship, correct? if so you would need to use belongsTomany() method inside Product and Galleries models, unless you have something very specific you shouldn't worry about having the ProductGallery model (as I understand it's just a linking model). See more here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set relationship on your models.

Products Model

```
public function galleries(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class)
}
```

And on your controller you can get data like this

```
Procuct::with('galleries')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

For a N to N (Many to Many) relationships you need to use belongsToMany() method, as described in: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

So in you Product model you would have a galleries() method that returns the relationship, as follows:

```
public function galleries(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Gallery::class);
}
```

And similarly in the Gallery model you would have a products() method:

```
public function products(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

If you want to get only the galleries of a product, you need to create an object of Product and call the galleries() method:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$product->galleries();
```

Or if you wan to return a list of products information including their galleries you do this way:

```
$products = Products::with('galleries')->get();
```

Check the documentation so you can have the full picture about other options you have such as using custom field names and etc.